# Моё имя есть не что иное, как корень «борщ-»(,) плюс суффикс «-ов»(,) плюс ещё один суффикс — «-ик»

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

> Моё имя есть не что иное, как корень «борщ-»(,) плюс суффикс «-ов»(,) плюс ещё один суффикс — «-ик».

Comment: Обе запятые нужны по 7-му пункту. Помните, я вам ссылку давал на повторяющиеся союзы? _Плюс_ — это тоже союз по сути.

Comment: @Максим Артём Если это повтор темы, не лучше ли закрыть вопрос.

Comment: @shampar Не, случаи немного отличаются. Даже я не до конца уверен в своем ответе. Хотя по большей части уверен, что 7-й пункт подойдет.

Comment: «...я не до конца уверен в своем ответе». Тогда зачем отвечать?

Comment: @shampar Как свое личное мнение.

Comment: Вас легко спровоцировать. Почитайте Правила сайта: «Отвечайте на хорошо заданные вопросы
Не на все вопросы стоит отвечать. Уберегите себя от разочарования и не отвечайте на вопросы, которые непонятны или не содержат конкретных подробностей, что не позволяет однозначно определить проблему; провоцируют обмен мнениями, а не фактами...».

Answer (score 0):

Первая запятая в скобках точно не нужна, а вторая нужна, поскольку придаёт характер перечисления.